# Is there a way of adding a menu to a google document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

With google spreadsheets, adding buttons to the interface with google apps script is as simple as:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var menuEntries = [ {name: "Say Hi", functionName: "sayHi"},
                  {name: "Get this citation", functionName: "main"} ];
ss.addMenu("Tutorial", menuEntries);
```

Is there something similar for google documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can now !

its  a new feature.

It is explained [in the docs here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs#custom_menus_and_user_interfaces):

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible today, but please star and track [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=721) on the Issue Tracker.